# Why do "git diff" and "git diff --color-words" get colored output differently?

Tags: git, terminal, colors, escaping, text-files

If I do `git diff` I get outputs like this:

[image]

but when I add the option `--color-words`, the output looks like this

[image]

Clearly the difference is due to what `--color-words` does.

But I would have guessed that the colors in the terminal, in both cases, are rendered the same way from the escape sequence perspective.

However, that doesn't seem the case. Here's what the two commands produce when redirecting their output to a file:

```
$ git diff src/packages.tex > log1
$ git diff --color-words src/packages.tex > log2
```

**log1**

```
diff --git a/src/packages.tex b/src/packages.tex
index acb4a7b..20b0624 100644
--- a/src/packages.tex
+++ b/src/packages.tex
@@ -11,6 +11,7 @@
 \usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
 
 % questi vanno in qualsiasi ordine
+\usepackage{attrib}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \usepackage{dtk-logos}
@@ -21,7 +22,7 @@
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{imakeidx}
 \usepackage{indentfirst}
-\usepackage[left, pagewise]{lineno}
+%\usepackage[left, pagewise]{lineno}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{luacolor}
 \usepackage{makecell}
@@ -37,6 +38,7 @@
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tikzscale}
 \usepackage{tipa}
+\usepackage{varwidth}
 \usepackage{verse}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{xfp}
```

**log2**

```
^[[34mdiff --git a/src/packages.tex b/src/packages.tex^[[m
^[[34mindex acb4a7b..20b0624 100644^[[m
^[[34m--- a/src/packages.tex^[[m
^[[34m+++ b/src/packages.tex^[[m
^[[36m@@ -11,6 +11,7 @@^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}^[[m

^[[37m% questi vanno in qualsiasi ordine^[[m
^[[1;32m\usepackage{attrib}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{booktabs}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{cancel}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{dtk-logos}^[[m
^[[36m@@ -21,7 +22,7 @@^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{graphicx}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{imakeidx}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{indentfirst}^[[m
^[[1;32m%^[[m^[[37m\usepackage[left, pagewise]{lineno}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{lipsum}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{luacolor}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{makecell}^[[m
^[[36m@@ -37,6 +38,7 @@^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{tikz}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{tikzscale}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{tipa}^[[m
^[[1;32m\usepackage{varwidth}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{verse}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{xcolor}^[[m
^[[37m\usepackage{xfp}^[[m
```

(In the latter, the `^[` is the escape character, which I'd obtain in Vim by typing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>, for instance.)

Why does `git diff` use no escape sequences for the color and still gets colored output and `git diff --color-words` uses escape sequence to render the same colors?

Comment: @Guildenstern, they are the same colors. Just the format of the diff is meant  to be different.

Answer (score 3):

`git diff`’s color output is controlled by `color.ui` and `color.diff`.

`git diff --color-words` does this according to `man git diff`:

- `--color-words` is equivalent to `--word-diff=color`
- In turn the mode `color` (the argument to the switch) implies
  `--color`
- `--color` means `--color=always` [1]

So you are running `git diff --color-words --color=always`.

Back to `git diff`: the default for `color.ui` is `true`, or
`auto`. Which means that the output is colored if the output is a
terminal.

This means that you are running:

```
git diff --color=auto
```

Which does not print any escape sequences if the output is a file. [2]

Meanwhile your other command:

```
git diff --color-words --color=always
```

Will always print escape sequences, even when the output is a file.

#### Notes

1. `always` means that the the output is always colored, no matter where
   the output is going (file or terminal); c.f. `auto` which colors when
   the output is a terminal but not if it is a file
2. It seems that Git uses isatty(3): “test whether a file descriptor
   refers to a terminal”. It seems that it also uses the same thing in
   order to test whether it should call the pager for long output.

Comment: _Which does not print any escape sequences if the output is a file_ Does it mean that `git diff --color=auto` will produce different output depending on what the output is? How can it do? How does it distinguish where stdout is pointing?

Comment: @Enlico Exactly. I don’t really know, but from some quick searching it seems that it uses isatty(3) (“test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal”).

Comment: @Enlico: note that many standard commands check isatty (on stdout in general) to adapt their output: `ls` can columnize and colorize its output on a terminal, `grep` colorizes its matches ...